# How do I pair an Apple Magic Trackpad 2 with RPi4?

Tags: pi-4

Can an Apple Magic TrackPad 2 be paired with a Raspberry Pi 4 , so that I can control the Raspberry Pi 4 with the TrackPad 2 via a wireless connection ?

If so, how do I set up the wireless connection between the two devices ?

Thank you

Comment: You would need to know the communications protocol over the link, not just how to set up the link.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried it, but:

- The device should pair with bluetooth without verification. If there is a prompt for verification, the code should be 0000
- AMT2 drivers are in the 4.20 kernel, so anything above that should work too
- open a terminal and run `xinput list`. It should list a "Apple Inc. Magic Trackpad 2" device. Write down the id number, you will need this later.
- with `xinput list-props` you can see what kind of properties you can tune with `xinput set-prop [DEVICE ID]`

Tune only if your pad doesn't work exactly as you want. You can also make the tuning permanent; have a look at https://gist.github.com/imabuddha/c34c732dcd11dbb278a87e7ce5330943 for some sensible values and where to put the files.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the parameters in the list ? Which do I use, and why ? This is all new to me.

Comment: I don't have an Apple trackpad, so you would need to experiment/google for the tuning parameters. I added a link of someone who apparently set-up his trackpad correctly.